# How to make multiple view type in RecyclerView using two data models?

Tags: java, android, api, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have the data that I get from API using the Retrofit library. The API working perfectly. The problem is how do I put the data into the list and display it using RecyclerView adapter. I tried using HashMap but it will crash the application. Can someone help me to show the right structure and solution of this issue?

The data from API

[image]

Report model

[image]

Record model inside the list of report

[image]

The data I already got from the API

[image]

The interface that I want to display

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you **flatten the model**. Instead of having a parent with a child, have only one level. Also, **use different data models for your UI and for Retrofit**. When needed, convert between the models. This way, things are not tightly coupled and you can do other things when coverting, e.g. format strings if needed.

```
// This is what the data model will extend
interface UiBaseModel { }

// monthly detail report
class UiMonthlyDetailReport implements UiBaseModel {

    private String month;
    private String total;

    UiMonthlyDetailReport(String month, String total) {
        this.month = month;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
}

// monthly detail record
class UiMonthlyDetailsRecord implements UiBaseModel {

    private String month;
    private String expenseName;
    private String expenseIcon;
    private String expenseTotal;

    UiMonthlyDetailsRecord(String month, String expenseName, String expenseIcon, String expenseTotal) {
        this.month = month;
        this.expenseName = expenseName;
        this.expenseIcon = expenseIcon;
        this.expenseTotal = expenseTotal;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getExpenseName() {
        return expenseName;
    }

    public String getExpenseIcon() {
        return expenseIcon;
    }

    public String getExpenseTotal() {
        return expenseTotal;
    }
}



// In your activity / fragment / viewmodel / presenter:

    List<ReportMonthlyDetailsReport> reports = ... // get your data from retrofit
    List<UiBaseModel> uiModels = ArrayList<UiBaseModel>();
    for (ReportMonthlyDetailsReport report : reports) {
        // First records, then report
        List<ReportMonthlyDetailsRecord> records = report.getRecords();
        for (ReportMonthlyDetailsRecord record : records) {
            // Create UI model and add to list
            UiMonthlyDetailsRecord uiRecord = UiMonthlyDetailsRecord(record.getMonth_label(), record.getExpense_type_name(), record.getExpense_type_icon(), record.getExpense_type_total());
            uiModels.add(uiRecord);
        }
        // Lastly, add the report
        UiMonthlyDetailsReport uiReport = UiMonthlyDetailsReport(report.getMonth_label(), report.getMonthly_total());
        uiModels.add(uiReport);
    }

    // Use the ui models (for the recycler adapter)
    MonthlyDetailsAdapter adapter = MonthlyDetailsAdapter(uiModels);
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter;
```

All that's left to do is the adapter. There are plenty examples on how to support multiple view types, simple unfinished example:

```
public class MonthlyDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final static int VIEW_TYPE_RECORD = 0;
    private final static int VIEW_TYPE_REPORT = 1;

    private List<UiBaseModel> data;

    MonthlyDetailsAdapter(List<UiBaseModel> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    class RecordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RecordViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            // code
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class ReportViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ReportViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            // code
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        UiBaseModel item = data.get(position);
        if (item instanceof UiMonthlyDetailsRecord) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_RECORD;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_REPORT;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof RecordViewHolder) {
            UiMonthlyDetailsRecord record = (UiMonthlyDetailsRecord) data.get(position);
            // bind record
        } else if (holder instanceof ReportViewHolder) {
            UiMonthlyDetailsReport report = (UiMonthlyDetailsReport) data.get(position);
            // bind report
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. override `getItemViewType(position: Int)` and return different type with your different model.
2. override `onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)` , you can create itemViewHolder according to itemType.
3. override `onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int)` , you can display what you need . remember to judge the item's `itemType`

In general, you need to create different itemtype  according to your model, then create different viewholder, finally display the viewholder with you model

Comment: The problem is how do I differentiate between CHILD and PARENT in getItemViewType? 

 private List<ReportMonthlyDetailReport> dataTotal;

   @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(dataTotal.get(position).getMonthly_total()))
            {
                return TYPE_PARENT;
            }
            else
            {
                return TYPE_CHILD;
            }
        }

Inside the List, there's another list of record which is the child of the report list

Comment: #### You can create a wrapper entity and create a list like `List<Wrapper>` .</br>
`data class Wrapper(
    val records : YourEntity,
    val report : YourEntity,
    val itemType :Int
`</br>

1. put all records entity and report info into list, such as `report - records -records -records -report -records -records `, and you need to set `itemType` in wrapper entity. </br>

2. use wrapper to override the itemType method.</br>

3. display view according to wrapper entity's `itemType`,if `itemType` is report ,you just need to get the report data in wrapper entity.

Comment: Already put the wrapper. The app is crashed when run the activity