# How to use two models for a single recyclerview adapter in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have three model class of  username, user and a post  just like this

`data class User( val uid:String = "" )`

`data class username( val usernames:String="", )`

```
`data class Post(
        val text:String = "",
        val createdBy: User = User(),
        val createdAt:Long = 0L,
val creates:username = username()

)`
```

and I have them connected to firebase.
Now i want to use both of these models in a single recyclerView adapter. How will i do this?
my adapter looks like this

```
    class postadapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post>, val listener: MainActivity) :
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, postadapter.postviewholder>(
    options
    ) {
        class postviewholder(itemview: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {
            val username: TextView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.userrrrrr)
            val createdat: TextView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.createdAt)
            val Text: TextView = itemview.findViewById(R.id.postedText)
    
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): postviewholder {

        val viewholder = postviewholder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.feed,parent,false))

        return viewholder
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: postviewholder, position: Int ,model: Post) {

        holder.username.text = model.createdBy.uid
        holder.Text.text = model.text
        holder.createdat.text = utils.getTimeAgo(model.createdAt)
    }

}
```

i also want to pass the value of the username model to the post model of 'creates'
also, in the onbindviewholder i want to pass the value of the username i created in the data class.

Comment: please someone help me i am stuck in this for 3days now

Comment: I think this is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/9846650

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638322/how-to-make-multiple-view-type-in-recyclerview-using-two-data-models

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for two models, just put everything that is outside, inside. Then use an identifier to access it through the model name.

```
DATABASE {
   MODEL_ID
        {
          MODEL_ID : 1000
          1000 {
                  EXAMPLE_DATA_ONE: 1001
                  EXAMPLE_DATA_TWO: 1002
```